# Readarray with preppended or appended values in Bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, append, prepend

In Bash if I want to get a list of all available keyboard layouts but prepend my own keyboard layouts I can do:

```sh
readarray -t layouts < <(localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts)
layouts=("custom1" "custom2" "${kb_layouts[@]}")
```

If I want to append I can do:

```sh
readarray -t layouts < <(localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts)
layouts=("${kb_layouts[@]}" "custom1" "custom2")
```

Is it possible to achieve the same in a single line, in the `readarray` command?

Comment: You want to append to array `layouts` that is already populated by the `localectl` command?

Comment: @Inian Yes, but do it at the same time, I mean prepend the custom values with the same `readarray` command. I tried different ways but it didn't work. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: To append to an array, you can use `+=` --> `layouts+=(custom1 custom2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the process substitution output `<(..)` is replaced by a FIFO for the processes to consume from, you can add more commands of choice inside. E.g. to append  `"custom1" "custom2"` you just need to do

```
readarray -t layouts < <(
  localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts; 
  printf '%s\n' "custom1" "custom2" )
```

This creates one FIFO with contents from both the `localectl` output and `printf` output, so that `readarray` can read them as just another unique non-null lines. For prepend operation, have the same with `printf` output followed by `localectl` output.

Comment: Oh I had tried that but I think I had forgot the `;` that's why it wasn't working. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `-O` option to `mapfile`/`readarray` to specify a starting index. So

```sh
declare -a layouts=(custom1 custom2)
readarray -t -O"${#layouts[@]}" layouts < <(localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts)
```

will add the lines of the command starting after the existing values in the array instead of overwriting the existing contents.

You can append multiple values at once to an existing array with `+=(...)`:

```sh
readarray -t layouts < <(localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts)
layouts+=(custom1 custom2)
```